# Yii Many to Many saving issue

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I'm having trouble saving a many to many relation. My database schema are as below:-

```
articles
- id (PK)
- content

tags
- id (PK)
- name

article_tag
- article_id (PK)
- tag_id (PK)
```

My Article model has the following relation:-

```
'tags' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', 'article_tag(tag_id, article_id)'),
```

However, when I saw using a Yii behavior, I get the following error:-

```
Table "tags" does not have a column named "article_tag(tag_id, article_id)".
```

I have run through everything from schema to relation and I can't seem to figure out the problem. I have tried using other extensions as well and none of them seem to save to the m:n table.

Am I missing something here?

**Additional Information**

Here is my CManyManyRelation Object; the foreignKey just doesn't look right.

```
CManyManyRelation Object ( [limit] => -1 [offset] => -1 [index] => [through] => [joinType] => LEFT OUTER JOIN [on] => [alias] => [with] => Array ( ) [together] => [scopes] => [name] => tags [className] => Tag [foreignKey] => restaurant_tag(restaurant_id, tag_id) [select] => * [condition] => [params] => Array ( ) [group] => [join] => [having] => [order] => [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Many-Many relation in the `Article` class you should put first the id of the Article and then the id of the tag:

```
'tags' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', 'article_tag(article_id, tag_id)'),
```

Then in the class `Tag` you should have:

```
'articles' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Article', 'article_tag(tag_id, article_id)'),
```

Edit: My bad I didn't realize it was saving the related model that causes the problem.
There is no build-in possibility to save the related record in Yii

For me the best solution to save a related models is the extension [activerecord-relation-behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/activerecord-relation-behavior/). The extension will be handling all the HAS_MANY and MANY_MANY relations.

Comment: Hi @darkheir, it's still not working for me. I have edited my question with output from CManyManyRelation. The foreignKey doesn't look right.

Comment: What is the yii behavior you are using?

Comment: Hi @darkheir, it was my mistake. I had to comment out all my validation rules in the model in order to test it out. It is working now. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Plus for the inverse ids order for @darkheir!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using yii-manymanyactiverecord extension to help simplify the process, you can find it here: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-manymanyactiverecord/